# Not able to update replication factor in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I am running a cassandra cluster with 3 nodes.
The keyspace1 is configured to run NetworkTopologyStrategy,

> ```
> [default@Keyspace1] describe Keyspace1;
>    Keyspace: Keyspace1:
>    Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy
>    Durable Writes: true
>    Options: [datacenter1:1]
> ```

I tried to update the replication factor by running this command on Node1 in cassandra CLI

> update keyspace Keyspace1  with strategy_options = {datacenter1:3};

But when I check again using describe Keyspace1, I still see the  Options: [datacenter1:1], the replication factor is not changed. I tried restarting cassandra, attempted repair and cleanup on all nodes, still no effect. What am I missing?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `[` `]` that wrap around the strategy options. Your update code should be:

```
UPDATE KEYSPACE Keyspace1 WITH strategy_options = [{datacenter1:3}];
```

If you require further details on how to update the replication factor of your KS through the CLI I recommend you have a look at the [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/operations/cluster_management#changing-the-replication-factor) documentation.